# At what rate does an electrolyzer store/retrieve energy?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

At what rate does an electrolyzer exchange energy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It retrieves and outputs energy at 10 EU/t (Energy Units per tick) per [Water Cell](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Water_Cell) and can store up to 15000 [Energy Units](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=EU).

From the [wiki](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Electrolyzer)